# What is the minimum deployment target for using UISplitViewController on iPhone?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, deployment-target

When the iPhone 6+ came out `UISplitViewController` was still restricted to iPad devices, so I rolled my own simplified split view controller for use in iPhone 6+. Consulting the [current documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller?language=objc) it seems that the restriction has gone and that `UISplitViewController` is now available on iPhone, so naturally I am considering to switch to `UISplitViewController`.

I haven't actively tracked the history of `UISplitViewController`, though, and I haven't been able to find out with a few internet searches in which iOS version the restriction went away. This information is important to me because my app should still support devices with older iOS versions installed. Currently the app's deployment target is set to iOS 9.

So what is the minimum deployment target I have to set in my app if I want to use `UISplitViewController` on iPhone? Is iOS 9 sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UISplitViewController` is available on iPhone since iOS8, so iOS9 is sufficient.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Maybe I can learn how to lookup such information myself in the future.

Comment: No "official" source, sorry. But this is a good source imho: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4613809-uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started. I found another site that states the same, so I'm pretty sure it's correct ;-)